# FrameLayout, how to move item under other item

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I create a layout with button, this button have logic and i dont want to integrate it.

So i think like:

When i have button, i need to add a char $, so i create a `frameLayout` and add here a `TextView`, i do this, but my `TextView` is under button, so i didnt see this `TextView`,

Here is my code:

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cash"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_radius"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:text="@string/_5000"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/dollar_$"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

And my question is, how to move item under other item in FrameLayout?
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the `elevation` parameter. By default a `Button` has a non-zero value of `elevation` while `TextView's` `elevation` is `0dp`.

Try manipulating `elevation` (either increase `elevation` for `TextView` or decrease `elevation` for `Button`) to match your exact case.

I suggest you apply both:

```
app:elevation="<your_value_in_dp>"    
android:elevation="<your_value_in_dp>"
```

Comment: Yea bro, u are right. Hah so easy too do, but i tired. Thanks for help :)